# how to make login w/ html, css and javascript

Tags: javascript

So, I have the HTML & CSS code already, but I need to make it so when you click button, it checks the contents of the input boxes and if equal to
Username = damon
Password = password
it lets you redirects to chat.html and if its wrong it does `alert("wrong").`

(I dont know JavaScript so I'm asking here.)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <input placeholder="username" type="text" >
        <input placeholder="password" type="password" id="password">
        <button type="button" onclick="" id="enter">ENTER</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="script/db.js"></script>
  <script src="script/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

db.js is empty and main.js has

```
function clickHandler() {
  if (username === 'damon' && password === 'poop'){
    window.location.replace("chat.html");
  } else {
    alert('Wrong!')
  }
}
```

Comment: So you need to bind an event to clicking the button and call a function

Comment: Are you aware that your users can read the source code with the username and password? They can also read `window.location.replace("chat.html");` and skip the login.

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoding or doing user login checks on client side is not recommended as anyone can read the source and find out your login credentials.

But just assume that you just wanted to learn and try it out. You may do it like this.

Inline Onclick Function Call:

```js
//this is main.js
function clickHandler() {
  if (document.getElementById("username").value === "damon" && document.getElementById("password").value === 'poop'){
    console.log("redirect to chat.html");
    //window.location.replace("chat.html");
  } else {
    alert('Wrong!');
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <!--Added id="username" to below input-->
        <input placeholder="username" id="username" type="text" >
        <input placeholder="password" id="password" type="password">
        <!--You may use inline onclick to call clickHandler function-->
        <button type="button" onclick="clickHandler()" id="enter">ENTER</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="script/db.js"></script>
  <script src="script/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Or you may do it by attaching onclick listener to the button to call function.